# Matrix exponential in terms of submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

I want to compute the exponential of a matrix:
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & I_{3\times3} & \boldsymbol{0}_{3\times3}\\
\boldsymbol{0}_{3\times3} & \boldsymbol{0}_{3\times3} & I_{3\times3} \\
\boldsymbol{0}_{3\times3} & \boldsymbol{0}_{3\times3} & b \ I_{3\times3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $I_{3\times3}$ is a 3-by-3 identity matrix and $b \ (>0)$ is a scalar. The submatrix $A_{11}$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, given by:
$$
A_{11} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -a_{3} & a_2 \\
a_3 & 0 & -a_1 \\
-a_2 & a_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is there any straightforward way to compute $\exp{(A)}$? After a quick search on Wiki, the most common approach seems to be a diagonalization of a given matrix, but I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward way in this case. Is there any useful theorem to express $\exp{(A)}$ in terms of $\exp{(A_{11})}$?

Comment: Are we given that $b$ is non-zero?

Comment: Diagonalization would be nice, but this matrix will not be diagonalizable

Comment: @BenGrossmann, you can assume that $b$ is positive. I have added it to my post.

Comment: We can guarantee that the top-left block entry of $\exp(A)$ will be $\exp(A_{11})$, but unfortunately the rest can't be described in terms of $\exp(A_{11})$ in any simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you do have to do something akin to diagonalization. However, we can manage to do so symbolically. Here, I attempt transform the matrix into its Jordan form.

First, we deal with the generalized eigenspace associated with $0$. As the only generalized eigenvector for $A$, we can take
$$
\vec v_1 = \frac 1{a_1a_3}\pmatrix{a_1 a_2\\a_2^{2} + a_3^{2}\\0\\a_1^{2} a_3 + a_2^{2} a_3 + a_3^{3}\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0}.
$$
Note that $A\vec v_1 = (a_1,a_2,a_3,0,\dots,0)$. For the Jordan basis of the zero-eigenspace, we can use the columns of the following matrix:
$$
\pmatrix{a_{1} & \frac{a_{2}}{a_{3}} & - a_{1} & 0\\a_{2} & \frac{a_{2}^{2} + a_{3}^{2}}{a_{1} a_{3}} & - a_{2} & -1\\a_{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & \frac{a_{1}^{2} a_{3} + a_{2}^{2} a_{3} + a_{3}^{3}}{a_{1} a_{3}} & - a_{2} a_{3} & - a_{3}\\0 & 0 & a_{1} a_{3} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & a_{1}\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0}
$$
Next, to handle the eigenspaces associated with $\pm i\|\vec a\|$, use the columns of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{- a_{2} \|\vec a\| & - a_{1} a_{3}\\a_{1} \|\vec a\| & - a_{2} a_{3}\\0 & a_{1}^{2} + a_{2}^{2}\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\\0 & 0}.
$$
Finally, the eigenspace associated with $b$ has a basis given by the columns of the following:
$$
\pmatrix{a_{1}^{2} + b^{2} & a_{1} a_{2} - a_{3} b & a_{1} a_{3} + a_{2} b\\a_{1} a_{2} + a_{3} b & a_{2}^{2} + b^{2} & - a_{1} b + a_{2} a_{3}\\a_{1} a_{3} - a_{2} b & a_{1} b + a_{2} a_{3} & a_{3}^{2} + b^{2}\\b \left(\|\vec a\|^2 + b^{2}\right) & 0 & 0\\0 & b \left(\|\vec a\|^2 + b^{2}\right) & 0\\0 & 0 & b \left(\|\vec a\|^2 + b^{2}\right)\\b^{2} \left(\|\vec a\|^2 + b^{2}\right) & 0 & 0\\0 & b^{2} \left(\|\vec a\|^2 + b^{2}\right) & 0\\0 & 0 & b^{2} \left(\|\vec a\|^2 + b^{2}\right)}.
$$
If $P$ denotes the matrix whose columns are the columns of the matrices listed above (in order and consecutively), then we can write $A = PJP^{-1}$, where
$$
J = \pmatrix{
0&1\\
&0\\
&&0\\
&&&0\\
&&&&0&-\|\vec a\|\\
&&&&\|\vec a\| & 0\\
&&&&&&b\\
&&&&&&&b\\
&&&&&&&&b
},
$$
where the "blank" entries in the above are zeroes.

The exponential $\exp(A)$ can be computed as $P\exp(J)P^{-1}$, where
$$
\exp(J) = \pmatrix{
1&1\\
&1\\
&&1\\
&&&1\\
&&&&\cos(\|\vec a\|) & -\sin(\|\vec a\|)\\
&&&&\sin(\|\vec a\|) & \cos(\|\vec a\|)\\
&&&&&&e^b\\
&&&&&&&e^b\\
&&&&&&&&e^b
}.
$$